# Ubuntu Server 16.04.3LTS Squashfs as root from Grub

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, squashfs

I'm currently trying to setup an x86 64bit system to use a Squashfs as its root mountpoint, but i'm being met with many issues. Currently I am using 4.4.0-89 kernel compiled with Squashfs. I am looking to do this on a hard disk, but just for learning and testing sake, I am currently trying to do this from a USB (not sure if this would create issues but I am doubtful).

I have set the device up as so:

```
Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           2048 14583807 14581760    7G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       14583808 15656959  1073152  524M 83 Linux
```

/dev/sdb1 is a squashfs filesystem of Ubuntu 16.04.3LTS that I created by using

`dd if=filesystem.squashfs of=/dev/sdb1`

and /dev/sdb2 is boot:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Oct  5 09:57 grub/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 40177135 Oct  5 09:28 initrd
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  6913440 Oct  4 13:12 vmlinuz
```

My grub config menuentry is as so:

```
menuentry 'test' {
        set root=(hd0,msdos2)
        linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1 ro rootfstype=squashfs quiet splash
        initrd /initrd
}
```

Currently when I try to boot I press escape to get rid of the grub ubuntu splash screen and it runs through the same error lines:

```
madm: No device listed in conf file were found.
madm: CREATE group disk not found
```

before finally showing:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/sda1 does not exist. Dropping to a shell
```

Where I have access to busybox's shell.

I have tried increasing the rootdelay to 300 which returned the same results as well as using the root partition UUID instead of /dev/sda1 which also did not work.

Within the busybox initramfs shell I cannot even see any sdx in the /dev/ tree.

I may be trying to implement this completely wrong but I am stumped on what to try next so if anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.